# Finding limit of the function by power series estimation

Tags: limits, power-series, self-learning, inverse-function

I want to prove that the limit of function $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{x} = 0$

Of course it is easy to find it by l'hopital's rule, but i want to find it using the power series expansion. But as power series of $\ln(x)$ is not nice, i need to use it's inverse, and that is  $e^x$. Can you please explain me how this derivation works? Procedure and steps.

Many thanks

Comment: Set $y = 1/x$ so looking at $\displaystyle \lim_{y \to 0}\frac{\ln(1/y)}{1/y} = 0$ and then use $\ln(1/y) = - \ln(y)$ so that you have to evaluate $\displaystyle \lim_{y \to 0} y \ln(y)$ which is well known to have the limit $0$ (see for example  Abramowitz and Stegun, http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/~macdonald/aands/page_68.htm), but you may not be happy at using this result (since to prove it requires L'Hopital).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=e^t$. We are interested in the behaviour of $\frac{t}{e^t}$as $t\to\infty$.

Use the fact that for positive $t$ we have $e^t\gt 1+t+\frac{t^2}{2!}\gt \frac{t^2}{2}$.

Comment: $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{x} = \displaystyle \lim_{t \to \infty}\frac{t}{e^t} = 0 <= \displaystyle \lim_{t \to \infty}\frac{t}{1 + t + t^2/2} = 0$
Is it correct?

Comment: I prefer to write thus;  We have $0\le \frac{t}{e^t}\le \frac{t}{t^2/2}=\frac{2}{t}$. But it is clear that $\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{2}{t}=0$, so by Squeezing $\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{t}{e^t}=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{x} = L$. Then we can take $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}e^\frac{\ln(x)}{x} = e^L$ which is the same as saying $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}(e^{\ln(x)})^\frac{1}{x} = e^L$. By properties of exponential and logarithm functions, we get $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}x^\frac{1}{x} = e^L$. Hopefully you know that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}x^\frac{1}{x} = 1$. Thus $e^L = 1 \implies L=0$.

Comment: You can't use a power-series approach because the radius of convergence is bounded.